# Make "quantile" classification with an expression

Tags: qgis, expression

I have a vector layer with an attribut called "value". To make the explanation easier, we can say that "value" goes between 0 and 100.

I can't find a way the calculate a new attribute called "effect" in expression panel for something like that:

```
CASE
WHEN "value" is under the 20% lowest possible value THEN 'Very low'
WHEN "value" is between 20-40% lowest possible value THEN 'Low'
WHEN "value" is between 40-60% lowest possible value THEN 'Medium'
WHEN "value" is between 60-80% lowest possible value THEN 'High'
ELSE 'Very high'
END
```

So as you can see, I have a problem to find a way to do `"value" is between x-y% lowest possible value`.

Comment: See also here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/470726/88814

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that `Percentile = (Number of Values Below “x” / Total Number of Values)`, how about:

```
with_variable(
'percentile',
array_find(array_agg("val",order_by:="val"),"val") / array_length(array_agg("val")),
    
    CASE
    WHEN @percentile < 0.2 THEN 'Very low'
    WHEN @percentile < 0.4 THEN 'Low'
    WHEN @percentile < 0.6 THEN 'Medium'
    WHEN @percentile < 0.8 THEN 'High'
    WHEN @percentile <= 1 THEN 'Very High'
    ELSE 'Undefined'
    END
)
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly though

Comment: Quantiles are the idea of dividing the range into classes so that each class has the same number of features.

Comment: Nicely done, I failed finding how to do that, I was trying with `count($id,"value"<
attribute( $currentfeature, "value" ))/(count($id)`

Comment: I love this solution, really useful, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would do it that other way...which I think is not the same statistically..these are not percentiles

```
CASE
WHEN "value" < minimum("value")+ 0.2*(maximum("value")-minimum("value")) THEN 'Very low'
WHEN "value" > minimum("value")+ 0.2*(maximum("value")-minimum("value")) AND "value" < minimum("value")+ 0.4*(maximum("value")-minimum("value"))THEN 'Low'
WHEN "value" > minimum("value")+ 0.4*(maximum("value")-minimum("value")) AND "value" < minimum("value")+ 0.6*(maximum("value")-minimum("value"))THEN 'Medium'
WHEN "value" > minimum("value")+ 0.6*(maximum("value")-minimum("value")) AND "value" < minimum("value")+ 0.8*(maximum("value")-minimum("value"))THEN 'High'
ELSE 'Very high'
END
```